# How do I get the current point in time in a recurring time interval?

Tags: c#

I have a specific problem I've been trying to solve, and I think I have the right pieces - I'm just putting them together incorrectly. It might be more of a math question than a coding one.

So basically what I want to be able to do is find where "now" is within an arbitrary recurring time period (say, 43 minutes), given a known DateTime that this period recurred. So you have an anchor point, and from that anchor point, you know that every 43 minutes this period starts over, where is "now" in the current period?

I'm sure it involves division and/or modulo, and likely a subtraction using the anchor...so I've been toying with this code, but it isn't giving me the results I'm looking for:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 43, 0);
        DateTime anchor = new DateTime(2018, 1, 5, 7, 0, 49);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        TimeSpan left = new TimeSpan((now - anchor).Ticks % interval.Ticks);

        Console.WriteLine(left);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me the piece I'm missing here? I'm not entirely sure what mathematical operations DateTime supports, or which ones I should be using in this instance.

Thanks.

Comment: it would be good if you could give sample input and expected output to make your question clearer.

Comment: Are you asking how to find how many intervals have passed between the anchor and now?

Comment: To me it looks like your code does what you want. Except that it's not giving you how long is left in the current interval. It's giving you how far you are into it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your anchor always in past, you can use this code. It will print amount of completed periods and how much time passed from begin of last period

```
var anchor = new DateTime(2018, 1, 5, 13, 20, 17);
var interval = new TimeSpan(0, 43, 0);
var now = DateTime.Now;

var seconds = (ulong) (now - anchor).TotalSeconds;
var intervalSeconds = (ulong) interval.TotalSeconds;

var cycles = seconds / intervalSeconds;
var momentInInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds % intervalSeconds);

Console.WriteLine($"{cycles} cycles passed. {momentInInterval} passed from last period");
```

I'm using `TotalSeconds`, you can change it to `TotalMilliseconds` to be more accurate

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how much time until the next iteration you could do something like this

```
TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 43, 0);
DateTime anchor = new DateTime(2018, 1, 5, 7, 0, 49);

var iterations = DateTime.Now.Subtract(anchor).Ticks / interval.Ticks;

DateTime current = anchor;

for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    current = current.AddTicks(interval.Ticks);

var untilNext = DateTime.Now.Subtract(current);

Console.Write(untilNext);
```

You can output the amount of past iterations, the current amount of time from the last and how much until next.